# Deserialize to different versions of a type

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I am looking for a way to be able to deserialize to different versions of an object.

Now I am already deserializing my xml strings into instances of my object.
My effort is to use Kellermans .Net compare utility to be able to detect whether my deserialized object has the same content as before it was serialized.

For simplicity we are assuming everything is good serializing the object to a xml string.

```
public class CompareHelper
   {
            public static ComparisonResult IdenticalContentInObject<T>(string serializedXml, T obj) where T : class
            {
                var deserialized= SerializeHelper.DeserializeFromString<T>(serializedXml);
                var compareLogic = new CompareLogic();
                var result = compareLogic.Compare(obj, deserialized);
                return result;
            }
    }
```

I am calling my comparer helper as the following:

```
var result = CompareHelper.IdenticalContentInObject<V1.MyClass>(mySerializedXml, instanceOfMyClass);
```

Now I could do the following for version 2:

```
var result = CompareHelper.IdenticalContentInObject<V2.MyClass>(mySerializedXml, instanceOfMyClass);
```

Is there a generic way where I can parse both versions of the class to my method and let my helper class iterate through the types?

I certainly can't do this:

```
var result = CompareHelper.IdenticalContentInObject<V1.MyClass, V2.MyClass>(instanceOfMyClass); // Also there can be x amount of versions of MyClass
```

I hope you understand this programmatically puzzle.

Comment: Almost sounds like you want any given version to know how to parse any other version's XML format, which I think would be to assume more knowledge that can be possible.

Comment: It is to detect backward compatibility. This will be included in our unittest, so we can detect a breaking change in our communication through webservices. I just want my comparer to be able to receive a collection of say my versions, so I can call my deserialize with Deserialize<thatversion>().